# Xcode. Ошибка при билде проекта. No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode

Доброе время суток.
Я получил недоделанный проект. При билде проекта получаю ошибку:

> BUILD_ROOT = /Users/vnavozenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vippie-cslbxuunpucpjmafggeuriydjnxx/Build/Products
>   cat: /Users/vnavozenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../info.h: No such file or directory

Уже очищал проект и удалял содержимое папки *DerivedData*. Пробовал удалять этот файл, но он генерировался заново. Содержимое файла - комментирована строка:

> // /Users/vnavozenko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AttachmentsModule-bffutswtjfyqwcbzqmkurtpxajhk/Build/Products

Нашёл скрипт с упоминанием файла info.h

> echo BUILD_ROOT = "${BUILD_ROOT}"
>   p=`echo "${BUILD_ROOT}" | sed -ne 's/.*\(^\/.*\/DerivedData\).*/\1/p'`
>   echo "//${BUILD_ROOT}" > ${SRCROOT}/OfflineHistoryModule/info.h
>   cat "${p}/../info.h" >> ${SRCROOT}/OfflineHistoryModule/info.h

Comment: Возможно при передаче проекта вам не отправили всё, когда появилась ошибка при первом билде ? ... мало информаций, попробуйте проверить когда генерируется этот файл, скорей всего у вас отсутствует файл info.plist

Comment: На каком этапе сборки выполняется скрипт для генерации `info.h`? Как я вижу, он создаётся в строке `echo "//${BUILD_ROOT}" > ${SRCROOT}/OfflineHistoryModule/info.h`  и может быть ещё не создан на этапе, когда его начнёт обрабатывать компилятор

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Проверьте в BildSettings для Projects и Targets нет ли подключенных links, path,libs с соответствующей строкой.

Еще можно проверить некорректные ресурсы в BuildFase в Targets. Раздел “Copy Bundle Resources”, внизу этого раздела могут быть ссылки на ресурсы выделенные красным цветом. Соответствующие ссылки надо удалить.